Plotting two or more non-competing cumulative events
I am trying to plot two events that do not compete against each other to avoid multiple plots. In this example, I want to plot patients who experienced side effect A and/or B. I can use survminer to plot either of them, or I can create a value that encompasses both, but then the plot will only reflect the time to the first of the two. How can I plot both simultaneously?
I tried survminer but do not know how to plot two independent variables.
